# Python program does not write to an Excel cell

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

First row is the header
I then want cells to be printed. The code runs successfully. Creates the file and the header but does not print the values like Cars, 10 etc from row 2. What's wrong in the code ? Thanks !

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = Workbook() #object of Workbook type
print(wb.active.title)
print(wb.sheetnames)
wb['Sheet'].title="Report_Amount"
sh1 = wb.active  
sh1['A1'].value = "Item"       #Writing into the cell to create header
sh1['B1'].value = "Quantity"
sh1['C1'].value = "Price($)"
sh1['D1'].value = "Amount($)"

column1 = sh1.max_column
row1 = sh1.max_row
print(f'no. of columns : {column1}')
print(f'no. of rows : {row1}')
for i in range (2, row1+1):  #want to write values from row #2
    for j in range (1, column1+1):
        sh1.cell(row=i,column=j).value = "Cars"
        sh1.cell(row=i, column = j+1).value = 5
        sh1.cell(row=i, column = j+2).value = 10000
        sh1.cell(row=i, column = j+3).value = 50000
     
print("file saved")
wb.save("C:\\Users\\Ricky\\Desktop\\FirstCreatedPythonExcel1.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that the rows are not being filled in is because of the for loop condition. According to the documentation, cells are not created in memory until they are accessed. So you only create one row meaning that the maximum will be one. By changing the value of row1 to a static number, you will see that it will put the values into the cell.

Comment: Thanks. I added this: to the code and now writing into the cell:   askrow = input("how many rows of data do you want to add: ")
askrow = int(askrow)
column1 = sh1.max_column
row1 = askrow